# CSS 'You have no color set [...]' Warning

Tags: css, colors, warnings, w3c

This warning should be straight forward but I cannot figure out what's going wrong.

The exact warning message from the W3C Validator is: `You have no color set (or color is set to transparent) but you have set a background-color. Make sure that cascading of colors keeps the text reasonably legible.`

This is the css where the warning occurs:

```
body {
    background-image: url('./img/bg1.jpg');
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #007e29; /* <-- This is the line where the warning occurs */
}
```

According to the W3C Docu and some google searches and it is clear that for each `background-color` there must be `color` attribute for this element. But this is what I am doing? The `color` attribute is set to white and the `background-color` to a dark green.

So what is wrong in the CSS above?
I am sure I am missing something here... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Warnings in the CSS validator (and HTML validator) mean nothing mostly. I generally ignore them altogether.

Comment: Have you tried moving your `background-color: #007e29;` line before your `color: #fff;` line?

Comment: I just validated it successfully in W3 CSS validator.

Comment: I don't know why people are down voting you on a genuine question... The reason you won't get any errors, is because the `body{}` code alone validates, but as part of a presumably much larger css file, it doesn't validate.

Comment: @techfoobar Yep, nothing changes. all: Okay, thanks for the hint. So it must be caused by any other class but that's strange why the validator says that exactly this class fails. I'm going to dig into this.

Comment: It says your body fails, because all your other classes are overlaid on top of the body. This warning is caused because the cascading of colors will at some point become illegible in the eyes of W3C standards (ie , white text on a white background).

Comment: @Jeemusu Thanks. Would it be better to leave the color in the body empty and set it directly in `header`, `content`, `footer` and so on...? What is best practice here?

Comment: It probably won't matter, because you'll simply be moving the problem to another more specific area, which will give you the same warning. It would be best to just ignore it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CSS code posted does not cause such a warning. Without a complete example, it is impossible to analyze why the CSS Validator seems to warn about wrong line.

Anyway, when people get confused with this warning, the reason is that they have set e.g. background and content color for `body` and only one of those properties for an inner element. People often assume that any element inside `body` inherits color from `body`, but that does not necessarily happen when other stylesheets participate. This is why the CSS Validator warns about the situation. It’s just a potential problem, which does not materialize very often, but still a risk.

Comment: Thanks, I decided to ignore it. I wanted to solve it because I have a huge CSS file with 0 erros and only 1 warning (the mentioned one). But before I have to insert these two values in each class (which are hundreds) I will stick with this warning. ;) Anyway, thanks!